# Need bit help here (Asking me to update com.google.android.gms to 11.0.4) trying to use firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hemanthanil.homescopic"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'


    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0'


    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'


    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.2'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Update it then..

Comment: I did.It says support libraries must use the exact same version specification@JuanCruzSoler

Comment: Yes, as it says upgrade your libraries to the same version

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
```

To this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
```

Comment: Didn't made any effect.It says support libraries must use the exact same version specification